# Don't display number greater than 72

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample site [here](http://webfro.gs/south/toc2/).

In the bottom of the document, there's a section labeled 'Potential Gen Ed TOC'.

If you open the Accordion labeled Composition, you'll see dropdown menus on the right.

As you can see, in this JavaScript, it was based on whether or not a checkbox was activated. Then the 'Potential Gen Ed TOC' would display a number based on the assigned value.

```
$(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#CourseMenu :checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        $('#total_potential').html(sum);
    });
});
```

As you continue to check boxes throughout the different courses, a sum would be displayed.

What' I'm trying to do now, is eliminate the checkbox trigger in the JS. I've replaced them with dropdown menus that say, "Credits - Select Credit".

Whenever someone selects a value, the "Potential Gen Ed TOC" slowly increases based on that value.

I would assume that all I have to do is assign **value="Any Number"** and the JavaScript would pick up on that.

In the JavaScript (above), I'm having trouble accounting for pulling these values from the dropdown menus. As you can see the JS is based on checked boxes.

Once I'm able to pull values from the dropdown menu, I want to have these values add up, but never display a number higher than 72, no matter how many total transfer credits are selected.

Does that make sense?

Edit: Here is some markup to understand where I'm trying to pull the values from (dropdown menu)...

```
          <fieldset name = Comunication>
            <legend>Transfer Course Information</legend>
            <label for="School Int.">School Int.</label> 
            <input name="School Int." type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" /> &nbsp; 

            <label for="ID">ID</label>
            <input name="ID" type="text" id="ID" size="8" /> &nbsp; 

            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="25" />&nbsp;

            <label for="Grade">Grade</label>
            <input name="Grade" type="text" id="Grade" size="2" />&nbsp; 
            <label for="COM1"></label>

          <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
            <label for="Credits">Credits</label>
            <select name="Credits" id="Credits">
              <option value="0">Select Credit</option>
              <option value="0.67">1 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="1.33">2 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="2.00">3 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="2.67">4 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="3.33">5 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="4.00">6 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="4.67">7 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="5.33">8 QrtCr.</option>
              <option value="6.00">9 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="6.67">10 QtrCr.</option>
              <option value="1">1 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="2">2 SemCr. </option>
              <option value="3">3 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="4">4 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="5">5 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="6">6 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="7">7 SemCr. </option>
              <option value="8">8 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="9">9 SemCr.</option>
              <option value="10">10 SemCr.</option>
            </select>       
          </form>
          Transferrable
          <input name="COM105" type="checkbox" id="COM1" />
```

Comment: Some markup would be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with select inputs:

```
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72));
    });
});
```

**Important note**

You have some serious issues with your form HTML markup. You have repeating ids in some of your elements which represents invalid markup, id attributes must be unique in a page. Also some of your inputs have the same name, which mean only one value will be submitted with the form. You can use arrays in your inputs name to submit multiple values.

Comment: The #Communication select then affects the rest of the HTML values because they're all #CourseMenu. Or would I have to change all of them?

Comment: @webfrogs Sorry, I thought you only needed the ones from the communication tab, updated to use all selects in form. Also read my note as there are some issues you may want to correct in your page.

Comment: That's actually working now. I should have thought of that. We're almost there.

Comment: @webfrogs If your issue has been solved, don't forget to mark the best answer by clicking on the green check mark next to it, to let the community know.

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72));
```

Will display the sum up to 72 then just 72

Comment: Your answer was correct too... for this bit of math. I plugged this into koala_dev's answer and we're all good. Props!

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
if (sum <= 72) {
    $('#total_potential').html(sum);
} else {
    $('#total_potential').html("72");
}
```

Comment: Think you mean `<=` so that it will display at least `72`.  Might want to throw an `else` in there that is hard coded, other wise you won't get anything.

Comment: This also doesn't help me pull values from the dropdown menu options. For example, if someone selects the value **3 SemCr**, then that value should then carry down to **Potential Gen Ed TOC**, but the number cannot exceed 72...

Comment: @webfrogs Then add retrieving `HTML` values to your question.  I don't see anything referring to that there.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieving HTML values"?

Comment: If you also want to add the value from the drop down, then you'll need to do `sum += <?$_POST['Credits'];?>;` but the above should still work.